# Can I apply for a transit visa if I stay two days in Dubai before going to a third country?

Tags: visas, transit-visas, uae, nicaraguan-citizens

Actually there are two questions. I'm nicaraguan but live in Japan. I will go to Zambia, with a transit via Dubai. I will stay two days in Dubai before continuing my trip to Zambia.

What kind of visa do I need? Can I apply for the 96-hour transit visa? Or a single-entry tourist visa?

When I return to Japan, I will transit in Dubai, but just stay in the airport. Do I need a transit visa?